# Why was this question de-duped?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question

I have been keeping my eye on [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17603055/1344955) which was previously closed as a duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/select-placeholder) which has more votes on both the question itself and its answers.

I just looked at the first question again only to notice that the duplication banner has been removed. I looked through the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17603055/timeline) but I can't see any entries for "reopen" and all "close" entries show "invalidated" under them with no additional info. I have an upvote on the auto-comment stating the duplicate-ness of the question which leads me to think that I was one of the ones who voted to close it as a dupe.

I still think that the question is a duplicate, and I would like to know what the reasoning was behind re-opening it, in case there *was* a reason, to avoid closing the question *again*.

Comment: `I have been keeping my eye on a question which was previously closed as a duplicate of another question `  No, it was not closed, as can be seen from its revision history.  It has never been closed.

Comment: The first question had close votes, but they have aged away the post has never been closed.

Comment: Also, if you really think it was a duplicate, why did you answer it?

Comment: @Servy I didn't know better at the time, and people are still finding the answer useful, so I'm hesitant to delete it.

Comment: Wow, that question has been into the close queue 6 times...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question has never been closed in the first place. It has had a couple of close votes, which put it into the review queue a couple of times, but each time the question didn't reach the critical 5 votes necessary to close it, before the close votes aged away [after four days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97556/close-votes-expire-too-soon-for-low-traffic-tags/97581#97581).

Comment: I had thought the question ended up being closed before, but evidently it was not. In any case, I've re-cast my close vote just now.